# Jenkins Pipeline Docker Network not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

So I have this setup

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        sh """ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d """
        sh """ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec -T app buildApp """
    }
    stage('Start UI server') {
        steps {
            script { env.NETWORK_ID = get network id with some script }
            sh """ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec -d -T app startUiServer """
        }
    }
    stage('UI Smoke Testing') {
        agent {
            docker {
                alwaysPull true
                image 'some custom image'
                registryUrl 'some custom registry'
                registryCredentialsId 'some credentials'
                args "-u root --network ${env.NETWORK_ID}"
            }
        }
        steps { sh """ run the tests """ }
}
```

And for some reason
the pipeline fails with this error. Most of the time, not all the time

`java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'my image'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: network 3c5b5b45ca0e not found.`

So the Network ID is the right one. I've checked.
Any ideas why this is failing?
i really appreciate any help.

Comment: Try changing `my image` to `myimage`

Comment: the name is just informative. That is not the real image name, or image name pattern

Comment: Can you post docker-compose.yml if you can. It would help create context on the issue. Additionally, post `docker network ls` and `docker info` for network overlay related information.